# TextAlign is not working on Controls.Find

Tags: c#

i want to check label's textalign with controls.find. But im getting error.

Here is my code:

```
for (int i = 0; i<=100; i++) {
   if (f1.Controls.Find("label" + i, true)[0].TextAlign == ContentAlignment.BottomCenter)
   {
      //My Code
   }
}
```

Im getting CS1061 error. Any help, please?

> Error: 'Control' does not contain a definition for 'TextAlign' and no
>   extension method 'TextAlign' accepting a first argument of type
>   'Control' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an
>   assembly reference?).

Comment: Well, you could cast it to appropriate type before checking. For example:   `(f1.Controls.Find("label" + i, true)[0] as Label).TextAlign == ...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the error says, Control does not have a TextAlign property, but Label has.
Since you know, it's a Label, you can cast it to a Label, like this:

```
((Label)f1.Controls.Find("label" + i, true)[0]).TextAlign……….
```